# Does HMS Video Kit support local video playback and video DRM?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have used HMS Video Kit in my Android app for URL playback. It works well with HLS video stream. However, I can’t find a way to play local video with the video SDK. Is local video playback supported? In addition, it seems that DRM is not supported in the current SDK.

Answer (score 0):

HMS Video Kit does not support local video playback. The video SDK supports online URL playback that is compliant with HTTP/HTTPs, HLS, and DASH streaming protocol. It also supports live streaming in "HTTP(S)+FLV" mode.

Regarding DRM for decryption playback, Video Kit will support HMS WisePlay DRM soon. You can find the details of WisePlay DRM at https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-wiseplay/.